# In IOS how to auto save the state when the app is in background

Tags: ios, background, task

we are developing a fitness app in IOS and there is requirement like we have to save state or activity every 1 min. So my query is how is it possible when the app is in background. is there any functionality for this ?

Answer (score 0):

When your app is go in background than `applicationDidEnterBackground` called after in this you can start your activity

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskIdentifire = 0;
     backgroundTaskIdentifire = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskIdentifire];
    }];
    [self TimerMethod];
}

-(void)TimerMethod
{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateMethod:) userInfo:self repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer: timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. my query is i.e my fitness app is running in the background and I want to save the activity each and every 1 minute. is it possible?

Comment: I don't think so it's possible while running in the background but after some time app is not work in background